# API Management Service Custom Domain Certificate

Tags: azure-api-management

We have an Azure API Management Service that uses a custom domain. We have it added to the custom domain section of the service, and have a certificate uploaded too.

The certificate has recently expired so we went to the blade and updated the certificate. However, when we hit the API the browser is still serving the old certificate, so we are getting an invalid cert error.

Does anyone have any idea why it might be holding onto the old cert?

Comment: Does Custom Domain blade now shows correct certificate expiration date and thumbprint?

Comment: Yeah everything is correct. Turns out the APIM is busted. Currently engaged with Microsoft support to diagnose. They can see the cert is not getting applied to the underlying VMs of the service, but have no idea why. Will post back with an answer if they ever figure it out.

Comment: @RayHogan did Microsoft give you any more details on the cause? I'm seeing this exact issue.

Comment: @MarkWragg We sat on support calls for many hours. Eventually were forced to recreate the APIM and deploy all the APIs from scratch (luckily we had ARM automation for them). Upon post mortem by Microsoft it was discovered that the underlying VMs that power the APIM wasn't letting go of the old certificate. Supposedly our APIM was using an older version and they said it shouldn't affect newly created instances.

Comment: Thanks Ray thats useful to know. My issue turned out to just be me not clicking the Save button ‍♂️. Its one of those interfaces that doesn't do a very good job of telling you that you have to do that. Glad it was an easy fix though!

Comment: Happy to hear that! Was afraid that there might be a new issue with the APIM service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long support calls the issue turned out to be a fatal flaw with that version of the APIM. We had no option but to recreate the APIM and redeploy our APIMs. Microsoft assured us that new instances of the APIM wouldn't have the same problem.